# Inline SVG vs <object> embedded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, svg, html4

I'm building an in-game browser RoR app for Eve Online. One of the requirements of my app is displaying an SVG graph generated by graphviz. I'm having some issues getting my requirements met within this environment.

No official documentation is available for Eve's IGB, but the wiki indicates:

> The new EVE Online in-game browser (code-named Moondoggie) is based on a technology stack combining two elements:
>
> Awesomium: A middleware layer that delivers rendered webpages as data parseable by a 3D engine. Awesomium is developed by Khrona Software.
>
> Chromium: A middleware layer that provides interprocess communication, webpage rendering, HTTP communications, and all the other basics needed for writing a web browser. It is, itself, based on Apple’s Webkit framework. Chromium is an open-source project championed primarily by Google.
>
> Because of this, Moondoggie is able to pass the Acid3 test and thus can support the full HTML 4.01 and CSS3 specifications.

I need the links I'm including in the SVG to have access to my app's javascript. Embedding it with `<embed>` or `<object>` puts the SVG out of the scope of my JS files.

Using `<embed>` or `<object>` DOES render the svg properly within the in-game browser. When it is inline like I have it below, it displays one line of text containing JUST the text elements from the SVG.

**Update**
Here's where I'm at. I'm pretty sure most of this is redundant, as I didn't notice a difference by just using the `render file:` inside my view on its own. I think the mime type registration is more for use with respond_to, but I'm not really sure how to use that in this scenario.

snippet of main view:

```
<%= render "map/map" %>
```

partial view file:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<head>
    <title>Embedded SVG</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <%= render file: @map.output_file_path %>
    </body>
</html>
```

config/initializers/mime_types.rb:

```
Mime::Type.register "image/svg+xml", :svg
```

I don't understand why it renders fine inside an `<object>` tag but not when inline. How do I emulate the environment inside an `<object>` in my main view? Or, how can I give the `<object>` tag access to my javascript functions?

Comment: Does this mean this Webkit based browser does not support HTML5?  Is using XHTML 4 an option?  For pre-HTML5, in my experience XHTML is really the most promising way of making it work.

Comment: There's 'prototype support for HTML5' but it seems to be hit or miss. I'm not really sure. That's literally all the documentation there is on what this browser does and doesn't support. I'm not really familiar with XHTML, nor do I have a good handle on doctype, but I'm looking at this: http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html. I assume I'll need to be using one of these instead of `<!DOCTYPE html>` to use XHTML?

Comment: Just an idea. It might be worth looking at what Google Charts does. They make pretty heavy use of SVG and Javascript, so you might be able to get some ideas there. Maybe you can dig into the pie chart on the interactive gallery https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery for ideas. I think they use the <svg> tag directly, which keeps everything in scope.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely check that out and see if any of it works in the IGB. At this point I'd be happy just to be able to reproduce this behaviour out of game.

Comment: Can you post an example of the actual rendered output of that render call?

Comment: @sicks does the inline svg have any redundant xml or doctype elements that are rendered to the page that you could try stripping?  Or another crazy idea could be to use jQuery $.get to load the svg and insert it in the browser dom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to access the document inside an <object> or <embed> from the parent document. This is one of the (way too few) svg things ACID3 still tests.

[Here's an example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html) of how to modify an svg document from a script in the parent html document.

Comment: The object/embed needs event listeners from the parent. That's why I was using inline at first. Can you add event listeners to tags inside the `<object>` that call functions from my parent page?

Comment: Yes. Add the event listeners with `elm.addEventListener` and then in the function that handles the event you can call e.g `window.parent.yourFunctionInMainDocument(...)`, , slightly similar to this example: http://dahlström.net/svg/html/from-svg-to-parent-html-script.html.